# Sort sequence in order from FASTA file by python program

Tags: python

I was trying to create a python program that reads the fasta file "seqs.fa"
and have the program to sort the sequences in order by the name.

The Fasta file looks like this:

```
>seqA - human
GCTGACGTGGTGAAGTCAC
>seqC - gorilla
GATGACAA
GATGAAGTCAG
>seqB - chimp
GATGACATGGTGAAGTAAC
```

My program looks like this:

```
import sys

inFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
a = inFile.readlines()
a.sort()
seq = ''.join(a[0:])
seq = seq.replace('\n', "\n")
print seq
```

The expected result:

```
>seqA - human
GCTGACGTGGTGAAGTCAC
>seqB - chimp
GATGACATGGTGAAGTAAC
>seqC - gorilla
GATGACAAGATGAAGTCAG
```

My result:

```
>seqA - human
>seqB - chimp
>seqC - gorilla
GATGACAA
GATGAAGTCAG
GATGACATGGTGAAGTAAC
GCTGACGTGGTGAAGTCAC
```

The last four lines are the gorilla, chimp, and human sequences, with the gorilla sequence split over the first two lines.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to sort it or a way to fix the problem?

Comment: I have a couple of tips. First, use copy and paste, instead of posting screenshots. Second, open up an interactive python interpreter -- if you don't know how, [see here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html). Now execute each of these lines in turn. Look at the result of each one by typing `print a`, `a.sort()`, `print a`, and so on. Third, think about why `sort` is doing what it's doing. Then think about what information the file provides that would enable you to cause it to do something different.

Comment: @senderle Your comment made me look for the [homework] tag on the question :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't implement a FASTA reader yourself! Like most cases, there are some smart people that already did this for you. Use for example [BioPython](http://biopython.org) instead. Like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("seqs.fa", "rU")
l = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
sortedList = [f for f in sorted(l, key=lambda x : x.id)]
for s in sortedList:
   print s.description
   print str(s.seq)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with your code. The main one is that in the list returned by `readlines()` your descriptions and sequences are all separate lines, so when you sort the list, they are detached from each other. Also, all descriptions go before sequences because they have `'>'` in the beginning.

Second, `a[0:]` is the same as `a`.

Third, `seq.replace('\n', "\n")` won't do anything. Single and double quotes mean the same thing. You replace a newline character with itself.

Reading fasta files is not a very complex task for Python, but still I hope I'll be excused for offering to use the package I work on - [pyteomics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyteomics).

Here's the code I'd use:

```
In [1]: from pyteomics import fasta

In [2]: with fasta.read('/tmp/seqs.fa') as f:
   ...:     fasta.write(sorted(f))
   ...:     
>seqA - human
GCTGACGTGGTGAAGTCAC

>seqB - chimp
GATGACATGGTGAAGTAAC

>seqC - gorilla
GATGACAAGATGAAGTCAG
```

To save this to a new file, give its name to [`fasta.write`](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fasta.html#pyteomics.fasta.write) as argument:

```
fasta.write(sorted(f), 'newfile.fa')
```

Generally, `pyteomics.fasta` is for protein sequences, not DNA, but it does the job. Maybe you can use the fact that it returns descriptions and sequences in tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("seqs.fa")    
a = file.readlines()
i = 0
ar = []
while True:
    l1=file.readline()
    l2=file.readline()
    if not (l1 and l2):
        break;
    l = l1.strip('\n') + '////////' + l2
    ar.append(l)
ar = ar.sort()
for l in ar:
    l1 = l.split('////////')[0]+'\n'
    print l1
    l2 = l.split('////////')[1]
    print l2
```